# Allow SQL injection

Tags: database

I'm trying to use Drupal for a specific research purpose and it would be helpful if I could intentionally make a text box **vulnerable** to **SQL injection**. Specifically, it would be convenient if I can make the search box **vulnerable** but anything is better than nothing. How can I do this? As a point of clarification, I'm trying to do this from a browser, not the `api` or terminal. Thanks!

Comment: There should be no possible way to do this without changing code (that's kind of a big part of the database layer's responsibilities). If you somehow find a way, please keep it to yourself and report it to the security team ASAP, or it'll be Drupalgeddon all over again!

Comment: @Clive changing code is alright as long as it's relatively straight forward. Based on nvahalik's answer that seems unlikely though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only way to to do this would be to write a custom module and explicitly write bad code that would normally not pass community inspection.

I'll leave that as an exercise to the asker. ;)

Hint: Your module should also have a dependency on [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bad_judgement).

Comment: Hm, I don't have an issue writing some code but I'm a relative newcomer to Drupal. Is this something a novice can handle? Seems like writing a custom module is somewhat of an involved task

Comment: There is far less of a learning curve with Drupal than there are with other frameworks. Check out [the Drupal examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) project for a ton of examples of how to build modules. You might even be able to modify something there to get what you want.